# Issue with using vcr and guard jasmine in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jasmine, vcr

In a rails project using rspec, I have had guard jasmine running jspecs for a while. But I just included vcr for some regular specs and when I did, it broke jasmine.

```
09:23:13 - ERROR - Jasmine test runner isn't available: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: HEAD http://localhost:53212/jasmine with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}
> [#] 
> [#] You can stub this request with the following snippet:
> [#] 
> [#] stub_request(:head, "http://localhost:53212/jasmine").
> [#]   with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
> [#]   to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
> [#] 
> [#] ============================================================
09:23:13 - INFO - Guard::Jasmine stops server.
```

I tried calling `stub_request` as the error suggests in many different places but got nothing. I have also tried configuring vcr with `allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true` and `ignore_localhost = true` but with no effect. Does anybody have any ideas for how to go about fixing this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The problem was that the vcr config file I had was only loaded by rspec and not jasmine so of course the 2 options I tried wouldn't work. The fix was to simply require the vcr config file in the jasmine rake task.